# (A⊕C) ⊆ (A⊕B) ∪ (B⊕C)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and I don't know what to do. I know that A⊕B = (A−B)∪(B−A), and I've been trying to do proof by cases method, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to prove that if $\;x\in A\oplus C\;$ then $\;x\in A\oplus B\;$ or $\;x\in B\oplus C.$

If $\;x\in A\oplus C\;$ then $\;x\in A-C\;$ or $\;x\in C-A\;$.

There are only two possibilities:

1) $x\in B$

In this case if $\;x\in A-C\;$ then $\;x\in B-C\;$ so $\;x\in B\oplus C$

If $\;x\in C-A\;$ then $\;x\in B-A\;$ so $\;x\in A\oplus B$

2) $x\notin B$

In this case if $\;x\in A-C\;$ then $\;x\in A-B\;$ so $\;x\in A\oplus B$

If $\;x\in C-A\;$ then $\;x\in C-B\;$ so $\;x\in B\oplus C$

In any case $\;x\in A\oplus B\;$ or $\;x\in B\oplus C.$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x\in A\oplus C$; then you know that $x\in A\setminus C$ or $x\in C\setminus A$. Suppose first that $x\in A\setminus C$. Then $x\in A$, $x\notin C$, and there are are two possibilities: either $x\in B$, or $x\notin B$. If $x\notin B$, then

$$x\in A\setminus B\subseteq A\oplus B\subseteq(A\oplus B)\cup(B\oplus C)\;.$$

If $x\in B$, then

$$x\in B\setminus C\subseteq B\oplus C\subseteq(A\oplus B)\cup(B\oplus C)\;,$$

so in either case we have $x\in(A\oplus B)\cup(B\oplus C)$.

To complete the proof, suppose instead that $x\in C\setminus A$ and try to carry out a similar argument to conclude that again $x\in(A\oplus B)\cup(B\oplus C)$.

Comment: PRof. can you offer guidance here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656970/proving-an-inequality-for-any-alpha-0?noredirect=1#comment7515431_3656970

Comment: thank!.........

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $x \in A \oplus C$, then there are four cases to consider.

- Case 1: Suppose that $x \in A$, $x \notin B$, and $x \notin C$. Then $x \in A \oplus B$.
- Case 2: Suppose that $x \in A$, $x \in B$, and $x \notin C$. Then $x \in A \oplus C$.
- Case 3: Suppose that $x \notin A$, $x \in B$, and $x \in C$. Then $x \in A \oplus B$.
- Case 4: Suppose that $x \notin A$, $x \notin B$, and $x \in C$. Then $x \in A \oplus C$.