# Proving $ \left| \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 + \dfrac{\alpha}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 $ for any $\alpha > 0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> For $\alpha > 0$, we want to prove that
>
> $$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{\alpha}
>  \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 + \dfrac{\alpha}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2 $$

### attempt

We may rewrite our inequality as

$$ \sum \alpha a_k b_k \leq \sum a_k^2 + \sum \left( \frac{b_k \alpha }{2} \right)^2 $$

Now, we may apply $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab $ as follows:

$$ \alpha a_k b_k = 2 a_k \dfrac{ b_k \alpha}{2} \leq a_k^2 + \left( \dfrac{b_k \alpha }{2} \right)^2$$

Now, adding up from $k=1$ to $n$ proves our result. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s basically sound, but there are a couple of places where you need to be a little more careful, because you’re ignoring the absolute value. When you multiply through by $\alpha$, you actually get

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha a_kb_k\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{b_k\alpha}2\right)^2\;.$$

Then you want to use the inequality $a^2+b^2\ge 2|ab|$ to say that

$$\alpha|a_kb_k|=2\left|a_k\frac{b_k\alpha}2\right|\le a_k^2+\left(\frac{b_k\alpha}2\right)^2\;.$$

Now you can sum over $k$:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha a_kb_k\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha|a_kb_k|\le\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{b_k\alpha}2\right)^2\;.$$

Comment: Prof Scott can you help us with this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657302/prove-that-the-sequence-a-n-n-converges

Comment: Thank you!.....