# Prove that the sequence $(a_n/n)$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)$ be a positive and monotonically increasing sequence that
> satisfies
>
> $$ a_{n \cdot m} \geq n a_m \; \; \; \; \text{for} \; \; n,m \in
>  \mathbb{N} $$
>
> Suppose $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\{ \dfrac{a_n}{n} \right\} < +
>  \infty $, Prove ${\bf carefully}$ that $\left( \dfrac{ a_n }{n}
>  \right) $ ${\bf converges}$

### Attempt:

By hypothesis, if $\alpha$ is the supremum of the sequence, then $\dfrac{a_n}{n} \leq \alpha $ so we observe that $(a_n/n)$ is bounded. If we can prove that is monotonic, then we are done. Let $b_n = a_n/n$. Then, we have

$$ \dfrac{b_{n+1} }{b_n} = \dfrac{n}{n+1} \cdot \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > \dfrac{n}{n+1} $$

Which leads nowhere. But, if we use the property of the sequence with $m=1$ we see that

$$ a_n \geq n a_1 $$

And in particular with $n$ replaced by $n+1$ one sees that $a_{n+1} \geq (n+1) a_1 $ or that $\dfrac{ a_{n+1} }{n+1} \geq a_1 $. Now, Id be tempted to say that

$$ \dfrac{ a_{n+1} }{n+1} - \dfrac{ a_n }{n} \geq a_1 - a_1 = 0 $$

but unfortunaly the inequality is not always true. Am I on the right directio nto solve this problem?Any hint/suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Note that the given inequality can be rearranged to yield $b_{n \cdot m} \geq b_m$

Comment: Also, with your observation, we can conclude that
$$
\frac{b_{n+m}}{b_n} > \frac{n}{n+m} \implies b_{n+m} > \frac{n}{n+m} b_n
$$

Comment: I know the inequality is just simply false. What other approach would you suggest?

Comment: The sequence (communicated to me by @bottledcaps) $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 3$, $a_3 =3$, $a_n = 7n$ for $ n \geq 4$ seems to be a counterexample to the monotonicity of $a_n/n$ between $2$ and $3$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clearly $\limsup_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{k} \le \sup_n \frac{a_n}{n}$. Fix $n \ge 1$. For $k \ge 1$, write $k = nq+r$ for $0 \le r \le n-1$. Then $\frac{a_k}{k} = \frac{a_{nq+r}}{nq+r} \ge \frac{a_{nq}}{nq+r} \ge \frac{qa_n}{qn+r}$. So, $\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{k} \ge \frac{a_n}{n}$. It follows that $\liminf_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{k} \ge \sup_n \frac{a_n}{n}$.

Comment: +1: Nice argument.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach I think will lead to a solution:

As per the counterexample in the comment, trying to prove monotonicity will fail. But part of the counterexample is that in order to create the break in monotonicity, we had to increase the constant greatly, impacting the rest of the sequence. Also we have that $a_n$'s growth is at most linear, otherwise the $a_n/n$ sequence isn't bounded.

So assume we have infinitely many breaks in monotonicity. Each break in monotonicity will impact the later terms by forcing the linear constant up. If there are infinitely many breaks then (I think) one can show that this lower bound for the linear constant is unbounded.

Comment: Unfortunately, this intuition by itself doesn't work: if we ignore the condition $b_{mn}\geq b_n$ (which is not expressed in the intuition), then the intuition fails when e.g. $b_n=a_n/n=2^{\lfloor log_2 n\rfloor}/n$. If we [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cda3ns6hfc) this function, we see infinitely many "breaks in monotonicity", where the function decays proportional to 1/n (due to the condition that $a_n$ is increasing). But it doesn't converge since the function "waits" exponentially longer for the value to fall back down to 1/2 each time. (continued)

Comment: (continued) For me, the key insight was that, due to $b_{mn}\geq b_n$, the amount of time the function can "wait" is bounded by a constant, therefore the amount that the function can fall every time gets smaller and smaller allowing it to converge. ([plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pnyoefcsdg))

Comment: I am unsure if this will lead to a solution, and it seems that the question has been solved. However I think the part "Each break in monotonicity will impact the later terms by forcing the linear constant up." is what encodes that condition.

Comment: I did reach a solution (I think it is the same as mathworker21's)